# Cannot create multiple VM using a single image file in azure resource manager portal

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, image-file

I have created an image file in resource manager portal.And I tried to create multiple VMs using that created image file. But the exception  occurs as follows: **New-AzureRmVM : InvalidParameterConflictingProperties: The property 'imageReference' cannot be used together withproperty 'image'.** I am able to create only one VM using that image file. Please let me know is there any solution.

Comment: are you sure you're using it as an image and not as a primary disk?

Comment: Yes am using an image file only. $vm=Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $diskName -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage -SourceImageUri $sourceImageUri -Windows
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VM $vm    In this $sourceImageUri is the image file am using for creating VM.